# telerik grid edit with validators seems overlapped

Tags: asp.net, telerik-grid, editmode, radajaxmanager

i have a telerik grid for asp.net ajax with AllowAutomaticxxxx properties set to true and EditMode="EditForms".
The mastertableview is for Divisions and detail table is for functions. Currently am able to insert new division and function and also edit division and function. i am using required field validator for both divisions and functions. now am facing a problem. the validator appears as overlapped when opening one edit function and one insert division.i mean when they are opened at the same time, and when i edited the function and clicked the update button, the validator for division name appears!!
1 more thing i have used ajaxmanager for the grid and i am not sure whether this is the issue.

Answer (score 2):

i solved this issue by setting validationgroup for each edit and delete like this in the itemCreated event of the grid

```
   If TypeOf e.Item Is Telerik.Web.UI.GridEditableItem AndAlso e.Item.IsInEditMode Then

        If "Divisions".Equals(e.Item.OwnerTableView.Name) Then

            Dim rvDivisionName = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("rvDivisionName"), RequiredFieldValidator)
            If TypeOf e.Item Is Telerik.Web.UI.GridEditFormInsertItem Then
                rvDivisionName.ValidationGroup = "addDivisionRowValidation"
                TryCast(TryCast(e.Item, Telerik.Web.UI.GridEditFormItem).FindControl("PerformInsertButton"), LinkButton).ValidationGroup = "addDivisionRowValidation"
            Else
                rvDivisionName.ValidationGroup = "editDivisionRowValidation"
                TryCast(TryCast(e.Item, Telerik.Web.UI.GridEditFormItem).FindControl("UpdateButton"), LinkButton).ValidationGroup = "editDivisionRowValidation"
            End If
        ElseIf "Functions".Equals(e.Item.OwnerTableView.Name) Then
            Dim rvFunctionName = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("rvFunctionName"), RequiredFieldValidator)
            Dim rvFunctionRoleName = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("rvFunctionRoleName"), RequiredFieldValidator)
            If TypeOf e.Item Is Telerik.Web.UI.GridEditFormInsertItem Then
                rvFunctionName.ValidationGroup = "addFunctionRowValidation"
                rvFunctionRoleName.ValidationGroup = "addFunctionRowValidation"
                TryCast(TryCast(e.Item, Telerik.Web.UI.GridEditFormItem).FindControl("PerformInsertButton"), LinkButton).ValidationGroup = "addFunctionRowValidation"
            Else
                rvFunctionName.ValidationGroup = "editFunctionRowValidation"
                rvFunctionRoleName.ValidationGroup = "editFunctionRowValidation"
                TryCast(TryCast(e.Item, Telerik.Web.UI.GridEditFormItem).FindControl("UpdateButton"), LinkButton).ValidationGroup = "editFunctionRowValidation"
            End If
        End If
    End If
```